# P2P Network: Python sockets not receiving data from other nodes

Tags: python

I have checked the documentation online and several Stackoverflow posts, but cannot debug my code. I think I am incorrectly sending bytes, so the other nodes connected to the socket cannot 'hear' the calls.

Is there something wrong with my use of sendall(), or something wrong with how I'm packing my bytestring?

```
import logging
from random import randint
import socket
import sys
import time
import threading


class Server:

    connections = list()
    peers = list()

    def __init__(self):
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        s.bind(('0.0.0.0', 10000))
        s.listen(1)
        logging.info('Successfully started the server on port 10000.')

        while True:
            c, a = s.accept()
            logging.info('New client node joins pool.')

            t = threading.Thread(target=self.handler, args=(c, a))
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()

            self.connections.append(c)
            self.peers.append(a[0])
            logging.info('New node connected: {}'.format(str(a[0])))
            self.send_peers()

    def handler(self, c, a):
        while True:
            data = c.recv(1024)

            logging.info('Sending data: {}'.format(data))

            for connection in self.connections:
                connection.sendall(data)

            if not data:
                logging.info('Node disconnected: {}:{}'.format(str(a[0]), str(a[1])))
                self.connections.remove(c)
                self.peers.remove(a[0])
                c.close()
                self.send_peers()
                break

    def send_peers(self):
        """Sends the list of peers in the swarm to all connected peers."""
        p = ''

        for peer in self.peers:
            p = p + peer + ','

        for connection in self.connections:
            connection.sendall(b'\x11' + p.encode())


class Client:
    def __init__(self, address):
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        s.connect((address, 10000))
        logging.info('Successfully made a client connection at: {}. Listening..'.format(address))
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.send_message, args=(s,))
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

        while True:
            data = s.recv(1024)
            print(data)

            if not data:
                break

            if data[0:1] == b'\x11':
                # Message prefixed with \x11, so we know it is a new node message
                self.update_peers(data[1:])
            else:
                # Since the message received isn't prefixed with \x11, we know it is a message
                logging.info('Received message: {}'.format(data.decode()))

    @staticmethod
    def send_message(s):
        """Sends a message to all connected nodes."""
        while True:
            message = str(input('Enter message: ')).encode()
            s.sendall(message)
            logging.info('Sending message: {}'.format(message.decode()))

    @staticmethod
    def update_peers(peer_data):
        """Refreshes the local copy of all connected nodes."""
        logging.info('Node dropped/connected. Updating connected peers list.')
        Tracker.peers = peer_data.decode.split(',')[:-1]


class Tracker:
    """Tracks the Peers connected within the swarm.

    This is a separate class due to data accessibility. We want to be able to access the peers list
    from outside the Client and Server classes.
    """
    peers = ['127.0.0.1']


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
                        level=logging.INFO,
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    logging.info('Connecting..')

    while True:
        try:
            time.sleep(randint(1, 5))
            for peer in Tracker.peers:
                try:
                    server = Server()
                except KeyboardInterrupt:
                    sys.exit(0)
                except:
                    logging.warning('Server is already started. Becoming a client node.')

                try:
                    client = Client(peer)
                except KeyboardInterrupt:
                    sys.exit(0)
                except:
                    logging.warning('Could not become a client node.')
                    pass

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: This is a lot of code. What is the problem? Where _exactly_ does it _not work_? Can you give us a [mcve]?

Comment: I was thinking about reducing the code snippet down to a single function, but I figured it would help to see the whole picture. What I'm trying to achieve is have a node connect, and have all connected nodes be aware of this new node. When a node sends a message, all nodes receive the message that was sent.

Comment: I don't see how you expect your `Client` nodes to start executing. Your code will block on line 123 and no clients will ever be created.